# Autoregressive Moving Average ARMA with statsmodels

Tags: predictive-modeling, forecast

Can I please get direction on what is wrong in the code? All forecasts provide output except the ones listed bellow.

so basically doesn't pick `['UserDefinedData4']` and `['ItemId']` separate ... only when both are  in `group_level` ...

this link is with the program:
[program location](https://github.com/sergiubuciumas/issue)

```
elif forecast_type == 4:
    # forecast weekly order quantity at item level with the dummy variable 'Quarter' using AR(8)
    mape = forecast(dataset, 'W', ['ItemId'], 'Quarter', 8, output_file)
elif forecast_type == 5:
    # forecast weekly order quantity at item level with the dummy variable 'Month' using AR(8)
    mape = forecast(dataset, 'W', ['ItemId'], 'Month', 8, output_file)
elif forecast_type == 6:
    # forecast monthly order quantity at item level with the dummy variable 'Quarter' using AR(2)
    mape = forecast(dataset, 'M', ['ItemId'], 'Quarter', 2, output_file)
elif forecast_type == 7:
    # forecast weekly order quantity at customer level with the dummy variable 'Month' using AR(8)
    mape = forecast(dataset, 'W', ['UserDefinedData4'], 'Month', 8, output_file)
elif forecast_type == 8:
    # forecast weekly order quantity at customer level with the dummy variable 'Quarter' using AR(8)
    mape = forecast(dataset, 'W', ['UserDefinedData4'], 'Quarter', 8, output_file)
elif forecast_type == 9:
    # forecast monthly order quantity at customer level with the dummy variable 'Quarter' using AR(2)
    mape = forecast(dataset, 'M', ['UserDefinedData4'], 'Quarter', 2, output_file)
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Don't know if this answer is helpful, but I found ARIMA modeling way easier in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and I will post the answer in case anybody will get this issue with ARMA.

```
model = sm.tsa.ARMA(endog=dataset_period[col], order=(nlag,0), exog= dataset_period[dummy_variable_period]).fit()
dataset_period['predict_'+str(col[1])+'_'+str(col[2])] = model.predict()
dataset_period['ape_'+str(col[1])+'_'+str(col[2])] = abs(  (dataset_period[col] - dataset_period['predict_'+str(col[1])+'_'+str(col[2])]) / dataset_period[col])
valid_ape = dataset_period['ape_'+str(col[1])+'_'+str(col[2])][dataset_period['ape_'+str(col[1])+'_'+str(col[2])] < 50]
```

> issue was with the parameters. the model accepted 2 parameters for ***group_level*** and I was basically providing 1 so in this case automatically become *zero and raise error*.
>
> solved with creating a new ***def*** and the model will use single column as the parameter for ***group_level***

```
model = sm.tsa.ARMA(endog=dataset_period[col], order=(nlag,0),exog= dataset_period[dummy_variable_period]).fit()
dataset_period['predict_'+str(col[1])] = model.predict()
dataset_period['ape_'+str(col[1])] = abs((dataset_period[col] - dataset_period['predict_'+str(col[1])]) / dataset_period[col])
valid_ape = dataset_period['ape_'+str(col[1])][dataset_period['ape_'+str(col[1])] < 50]`
```